# Sqlalchemy session.rollback() after session.add_all(rows)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

What is the best practice for rolling back a transaction after using session.add_all() to add multiple rows? I am collecting some sensor data that is received in bulk every couple of seconds so I would like to add them all to a single transaction. Sometimes one of the sensors will fault and send an integer to large for postgres' integer column. Will I lose the rest of the valid rows with this code or will Sqlalchemey only roll back the rows that caused the error?

```
        logger.debug('Orm recieved message')
        message = message_queue.get()
        # Generate list of row objects to add to session
        rows = factory.get_objects_list(message)
        
        try:
            session.add_all(rows)
            session.commit()
        except DataError as e:
            logger.error(f'Rolled back due to {e}')
            session.rollback()

        session.close()

        message_queue.task_done()
        logger.debug("Message processed.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the rows will be rolled back even if only one failed.  This is done because a transaction is all or nothing.  I would suggest prechecking for this case and then setting a flag, ie. `row.overflow = True` where `overflow = Column(Boolean, default=False)` and/or just setting the integer to the max/min value before committing. Depending on the column type you can see the max/min values in the [postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html).

There are datatypes that would hold any value but I can understand that the size might add up quickly if you are creating millions and millions of rows.

Here is some psuedo code to pre-check for overflow and then update the rows to prevent an exception.  There might be a postgresql specific way to handle this but this should work in the app code.

```py
# These value are for the integer data type.
MAX_READING=2147483647
MIN_READING=-2147483648
for row in rows:
    if row.reading > MAX_READING:
        row.overflow = True
        row.reading = MAX_READING
    elif row.reading < MIN_READING:
        row.overflow = True
        row.reading = MIN_READING

#... continue to add_all
```